# JavaScript style: which of these things should I pass as arguments to my namespace function?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, conventions

Here is a common practice in JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    ...code...
})(jQuery);
```

I understand the wrapper function (it prevents pollution of the global namespace), but many libraries (like jQuery, Underscore, etc.) already define short names (`$` and `_`, respectively) at global scope for me to use. I wonder what the advantage to this approach is. Just to rename `jQuery` to something shorter? Prevent me from overwriting `$`? Make it easier to swap in another library later? I guess none of these seem really convincing to me.

Furthermore, I have also seen this:

```
(function(_) {
    ...code...
})(_);
```

Nothing is even renamed here. I have even seen:

```
(function(global) {
    ...code...
})(this); // or window, perhaps
```

What is wrong with just using `window` directly?

So here's what I'm asking:

- Does this practice have a name?
- What are the advantages to this practice?
- Should I always pass in libraries I'm using rather than use them directly?
- Should I pass in `this` or `window` as a reference to global scope?

Comment: Why don't the reasons you listed seem convincing? How much convincing would you really require? It's just a simple function invocation, requiring little cost.

Comment: They don't seem *really* convincing because none of those reasons are relevant to my small projects. Rename to something shorter? There is already `$`. Prevent me from overwriting `$`? Not something I ever do anyway. Swap in another library later? Drop-in replacement libraries often use the same names to save programmers this trouble in the first place. ...All that said, from a defensive coding perspective, perhaps there are advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does this practice have a name?**

The syntax is referred to as a self-executing anonymous function. I'm not aware of any special name for passing global objects to the function.

**What are the advantages to this practice?**

- As you've noted, `var` scoping variables within the function will
  help de-clutter the global namepace.
- The `jQuery` example is typically used in plugins so that the plugin can make use of `$` while remaining compatible with `$.noConflict()` [(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

  ```
  (function($) {
      ...code...
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- In general, passing global or reserved objects (like `window`, `document`) as parameters can help reduce the size of your script after minification:

  ```
  (function(window, document) {
      // A JS minifier can now minify the all occurrences of `window` and
      // `document` within this function.
  })(window, document);
  ```

**Should I always pass in libraries I'm using rather than use them directly?**
**Should I pass in this or window as a reference to global scope?**

Only if minification or conflicting library variable names are a concern.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the advantages to this practice?

If the variable ('`_`', '`$`', etc) is later overwritten by some other code, your code will continue to work as expected.  It will use the value passed in when the wrapper function was invoked.

> Should I always pass in libraries I'm using rather than use them directly?

No, but if you have any concerns about the above, it's probably a good practice.  Also, if you look up AMD loaders such as Require.js, you will find this a familiar technique, as they do something similar to define the requirements for your module.

> Should I pass in this or window as a reference to global scope?

`this` has the advantage that the code will run where ever there is a global scope.  For instance, if you code might possibly run on a Node.js server, there is no `window`.